# android layout : use 80% of the screen

Tags: android, layout

I need to place a TextView in my layout , the textView has to be left aligned and use 90% of the screen

I know about layout_weigth but is there a simple way to do this ?

it would be great to be able to set % margins (like in css margin : auto;)

Comment: give its height width fill parent and static text size

Comment: How is layout weight not simple?

Comment: (just a joke) What % of screen do you want? 80% as title says or 90% as body says? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a empy View with weight 2 and change the textview weight to 8

```
<TextView .... layout_weight="8"><View ... layout_weight="2">
```

PD. place with or height to 0dp to expand by weight values